# Change angularjs url to different controller

Tags: .net, angularjs, model-view-controller

In the VisualisationController I've got this angular code:

```
$http.get('api/apinetwork/getnetwork').success [...]
```

The problem is that it's calling http://localhost:xxxx/Visualisation/api/apinetwork/getnetwork instead of
http://localhost:xxxx/api/apinetwork/getnetwork. How can I change the url to proper one?

Comment: Have you tried anything? For example inserting "Visualisation/" bit into the url before it's called?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've resolved this - just added this line before $http.get:

```
$location.path('/api/');
$http.get('api/apinetwork/getnetwork').success [...]
```